# Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php

I am having an associative array and want to get only the first key, however I am receiving a warning. See below my example:

```
<?php
// Warning=> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

$product = array("Test" => array(price=>"9999.00", priceOld=>"", percentageSaved=>0, currency=>"$"));

$keys = key($product);

echo $keys;
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\product.php on line xxx
```

Any suggestions why I get this warning?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What's does `print_r($product);` give you?

Comment: @James the above error is not explained on the reference page. Also: Google only drops me solutions if the variable has not been initialized, which is here clearly NOT the case.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using quotes for price, priceOld,...? If not it will be treated like constant. Or is it typo?

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale For `print_r($product)` I get `true` back.

Comment: Please add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to the start of the script to see the errors.

Comment: @frz3993 I get the above object like that back from my backend.

Comment: from where you're run your file it will give an error from desktop `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\product.php` path?

Comment: @James I was thinking the same, but it is clearly an array passed to the `key()` function. I only get a string in return...

Comment: So what does `var_dump(array_keys($array));` give you?

Comment: That is an array not an object, well unless you json encode it will become js object.

Comment: @Andreas `var_dump(array_keys($amazon));` gives me `null`.

Comment: I'm voting close now. Nothing here makes any sense. If it is an array then it should react as an array. If it's a string it should not print `true`. Something is not as the question states thus this question is not useful in the future. OP, debug your code. We can't do it for you since nothing here makes any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the array you pasted on the question is not property formatted. I can see some issue on your associative array keys(string without quotes). See it working fine for me after adding **quotes** on `string` key.

```
<?php
$product = array("Test" => array("price"=>"9999.00", "priceOld"=>"", "percentageSaved"=>0, "currency"=>"$"));
print '<pre>';
print_r($product);
print '</pre>';
$keys = key($product);
echo "Your key is: $keys";
?>
```

**Program Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [price] => 9999.00
            [priceOld] => 
            [percentageSaved] => 0
            [currency] => $
        )

)

Your key is: Test
```

**Edit:** If you want to get internal keys of *Test*, then use `array_keys()` method like this.

```
 print_r(array_keys($product['Test']));
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! Is there a way to format the array properly using a function?

Comment: @Anna.Klee Yes, I've formatted it on my answer by adding *quotes* on price, priceOld, percentageSaved and currency.

Comment: Thx for your reply, however you did this manually. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Comment: where you get this data? are you creating your own or getting from any other source like third party service or your backend service?

Comment: @Anna.KleeIf If understand you correctly, there is no way to add syntax to PHP code programmatically. The PHP code *is* the programmatically.

Answer (score -2):

please go and change your php version. change it to v5.6.31, worked for me.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a solution, `key` function has not changed from php4 to php7. Please consider to tell why your answer should resolve the user's question.